# Angular 6 using Datatables

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I'm new to angular, I'm trying to use datatables in my app however, for some reason I'm facing an error: ERROR TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function...
I've been searching on the internet for the past 3 hours and all of the answers that are posted such as:  adding import * as jquery from 'jquery' in my component but yet still not working, your assistance is much appreciated

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DoPayroll</title>
<base href="/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
 awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
          "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
        ],

"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
        ]
```

Comment: Did you do that: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

Comment: That's exactly what I followed and for some reason I'm still getting this error

Comment: Try this `import * as $ from 'jquery';` to get this line working you need to add in `package.json` file `"jquery"` and `"@types/jquery"` plugins.
If it didn't help then share code you are trying to execute.

Comment: Actually this worked !!,,thanks bro